# SOLR failed to create index for Cassandra 2.1.1 list which have user defined data type

Tags: solr, cassandra

> I m trying to integrate Cassandra 2.1.1 with SOLR, but SOLR failed to
>   create index with following error message.

```
16767 [qtp297774990-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Loading DIH Configuration: dataconfigCassandra.xml
16779 [qtp297774990-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Data Configuration loaded successfully
16788 [Thread-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Starting Full Import
16789 [qtp297774990-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [Entity_dev] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={optimize=false&indent=true&clean=true&commit=true&verbose=false&command=full-import&debug=false&wt=json} status=0 QTime=27
16810 [qtp297774990-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [Entity_dev] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={indent=true&command=status&_=1416042006354&wt=json} status=0 QTime=0
16831 [Thread-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter  – Read dataimport.properties
16917 [Thread-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  – Opening Searcher@6214b0dc[Entity_dev] realtime
16945 [Thread-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource  – Creating a connection for entity Entity with URL: jdbc:cassandra://10.234.31.153:9160/galaxy_dev
17082 [Thread-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource  – Time taken for getConnection(): 136
17429 [Thread-15] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  – Exception while processing: Entity document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from entity Processing Document # 1
        at 

org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:283)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:44)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.ListMaker.compose(ListMaker.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.TypedColumn.<init>(TypedColumn.java:68)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.createColumn(CassandraResultSet.java:1174)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.populateColumns(CassandraResultSet.java:240)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.<init>(CassandraResultSet.java:200)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:169)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.execute(CassandraStatement.java:205)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:276)
        ... 12 more
```

> CREATE TABLE dev.entity (
>
> ```
> id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
> begining int,                                                                                                
> domain text,
> domain_type text,                                                                                            
> template_name text,                                                                                   
> ****field_values list<frozen<fieldmap>>****
> ```
>
> )

**User Defined Type :**

> CREATE TYPE galaxy_dev.fieldmap (
>       key text,
>       value text );

**Please let me know what driver or Jar use to create SOLR index for latest CASSANDRA.**

Comment: Even datastax not giving proper info.. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfDataHand.html    :(

Comment: The link you are pointing to is an old version of the docs for Datastax's enterprise product. DSE has Solr integration out of the box. However, the latest DSE is on c* 2.0.11.

Comment: You might qualify to use DSE for free: datastax.com/startups

Comment: Phact - Do you have solution to create index for User defined data type. I able to create index for map, list and set  but not for UDT :(. The driver is not recognize the UDT.